# How to purge cached content every day via cache tag?

Tags: 8, caching, proxies

Drupal 8 page has a day specific element which is valid for current day. I would like to add a cache tag so that it can be purged in varnish/fastly periodically. Is there a way to invalidate cache tag periodically on Drupal8?

**Here is few FAQs/As:**

1. Why can't use max-age?

max-age can be used, but it's page level header which can get quite confusing when more than one component try to set it. Cache tag is kind of self-contained to the component.

2. Why don't run cron?

Trying to avoid explicit cron/job to do this as it's environment specific.

Comment: Notice that you are merely stating facts, without asking any explicit question. The question is then about code, but you aren't showing any tentative to resolve the problem. This is valid also for self-answered questions, for which the closing reasons are still valid.

Comment: You can use the max-age #cache which is in seconds so you have have a pre/process function on the element that would compute the time left in current day. Or you can create cache context for current day as well.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thanks for quick review. updated to reflect my question.

Comment: I don't really understand why max-age is not a solution either. If you want to say that having a high max-age results in caching within browser that you can't invalidate then that is correct, but there are pretty easy ways to avoid that, for example, you can use the Surrogate-Control header with Fastly: https://docs.fastly.com/guides/tutorials/cache-control-tutorial (I'm sure a custom varnish configuration can be configured to use a similar header)

Comment: @Berdir, I might be wrong here, but this is one element (i.e. a block) in almost all pages and we don't want to flush the whole page just to refresh this one component?

Comment: @vijaycs85 I don't know what you mean. whether it gets explicitly invalidated through a tag or implicty by expiring it, you have to invalidate everything that contains your content, both the block caches and any cached full page, in the internal page cache and varnish. tags vs. age makes no difference there?

Comment: @Berdir probably I misunderstood the many-to-many relationship part on https://www.fastly.com/blog/surrogate-keys-part-2. Thanks for your time. I will update the question reflect this change.

P.S: one more reason to use cache tag vs max-age is, when multiple component tries to set max age on a single request, we might need a custom implementation to decide which one should be used.

Comment: Multiple max-ages are reasy to resolve: the lowest number wins. If there are 3 components, with 5, 10 and 15 minutes max-age, then the page is valid for 5min.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50917/discussion-between-vijaycs85-and-berdir).

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code that flush cache on first hit of a day:

```
  public function build() {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    $this->handleCacheTag($build['#cache']['tags']);
  }


  protected function handleCacheTag(&$tags) {
    // Get the current date number.
    $current_date_number = date('z');
    $last_date_number = \Drupal::state()->get('module_name.foo.date_counter', $current_date_number);
    // If last date in settings is different from current day, invalidate
    // tags.
    if ($last_date_number < $current_date_number) {
      $invalid_tags = range($last_date_number, $current_date_number);
      array_walk($invalid_tags, function(&$invalid_tag){
        $invalid_tag = 'foo:date.' . $invalid_tag;
      });
      Cache::invalidateTags($invalid_tags);
    }
    \Drupal::state()->set('module_name.foo.date_counter', $current_date_number);
    $tags[] = 'foo:date.' . $current_date_number;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. I found that this didn't exactly worked as I had hoped/expected. When you enable all of Drupal 8's caching, the build process of a page controller is often bypassed because the result has been cached. This means the invalidation logic is skipped too. I ended up putting the invalidation logic in a hook_cron implementation. Another detail I changed in my implementation, is using `date('Yz')` to prevent problems around new years day.